# How do I split a String in Java up to a certain point, keeping everything after that point as a separate string?

Tags: java, string, split

What I am looking to do is split a given string in Java using a tab delimiter. After the seventh split, I would like to keep everything after that point as an eighth split. This last split will contain tabs also, but must remain intact.

Comment: Google `java split string`...

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - I just saw the correct solution below. You had already mentioned it in your comment but when I saw that it had not yet been formatted correctly so I didn't realize...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`split` method that takes two parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), the second being the split limit.  You can pass in a limit of `8`.  The eighth element will contain the rest of the string after the seventh split.

Comment: This is exactly the right solution.